# Angular 4 canDeactivate not respecting choice

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have created a simple canDeactivate handler for my form.  The function below does run when I try to navigate away from my form, and I can confirm the subscription returns TRUE or FALSE based on what button I click.  But regardless of the result the subscription returns, Angular never leaves my form.  Can someone explain why?

```
public canDeactivate(): Subscription {
  // Popup a prompt dialog
  const title = 'Lose Changes';
  const prompt = 'Are you sure you want to lose your changes';
  this.dialogWindow.show(EDialogTypes.EDialogYesNo, EDialogStyles.EDialogStyleWarning, title, prompt);

  // Based on the result allow leave or not
  this.subscription = this.dialogWindow.observable.subscribe(proceed => {
    console.log('Allow proceed: ' + proceed)
    console.log(this.dialogWindow.buttonPressed);
    // unsubscribe is necessary such that the observable doesn't keep racking up listeners
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    return proceed;
  });
  return this.subscription;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out something that works based on other SO questions.

```
// Allow the user to navigate away from this page
public canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {

  // Popup a prompt dialog
  const title = 'Lose Changes';
  const prompt = 'Are you sure you want to lose your changes?';
  this.dialogWindow.show(EDialogTypes.EDialogYesNo, EDialogStyles.EDialogStyleWarning, title, prompt);

  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.dialogWindow.observable.subscribe(buttonPressed => {
      const proceed = (buttonPressed === EButtonPressed.EButtonPressedYes);
      console.log('Allow proceed: ' + proceed);
      observer.next(proceed);
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
}
```